# PHP sent more then year

Tags: php

I try to modify the code to rates are send 2 years rather then only 1 year as the current code dos. How can I modify the code so it will?

```
$year_from_now=date_create(date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", time()) . " + 365 day")));


    $dates_array = array(); 

    foreach ( $tariffs as $site_room_type=>$tariff_type_dates ) {

        $counter = 1;

        foreach ($tariff_type_dates as $tariff_type=>$tariff_dates ) {

            $odo = "p".$counter;

            foreach ( $tariff_dates as $date=>$tariff_details ) {

                $this_date=date_create(date("Y/m/d" , strtotime($date) ) );

                $diff=date_diff($year_from_now,$this_date);

                if ( 

                    (int)$diff->format("%R%a") <= 0 && // Up to one year from today

                    (int)$diff->format("%R%a") > -365 // Not earlier than today

                    ) {

                    $jomres_room_type = $tariff_details['jomres_room_type'];

                    if (isset($room_availability['dates'][$date])) {

                        $qty_avail = $room_availability['dates'][$date][$jomres_room_type]['total_number_of_rooms_of_type_available'];

                        $condensed_date = str_replace ("/" , "" , $date );

                        $rate = $tariff_details['rate'];

                        if ($mrConfig['site_update_prices'] == "1" ) {

                            $dates_array[$site_room_type][$condensed_date][$odo] = $rate;

                        }
```

I have tried a few things like just change to  + 730 days but will not do the job.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: code have lot of variables and we don't know e]what those variables have

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? I see three foreach but none of them ends.

Comment: not able to add the full code

Comment: Why are you using both "Y-m-d" dates and "Y/m/d". Not sure that is the problem but it strikes my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 years'));
```

Or in more object oriented

```
$year_from_now = new DateTime();
$year_from_now->modify('+2 years')
```

Comment: In your code change +365 days with +2 years instead

Comment: I did but no luck still send only one year